# If I derive a formula for a paper do I need to put the derivation directly in a paper?

Tags: citations, mathematics, supporting-information

Let's say that I derived a formula that I am using in a paper, without any prior knowledge of the formula.  Do I need to then put my derivation directly in my paper, or could I submit a supplementary document containing the derivation, and then reference the supplementary document in my paper?

Comment: Perhaps write the derivations in your paper's appendix.

Comment: Is the formula a major or minor part of the overall paper? Does the derivation have any independent value beyond establishing the formula?

Comment: That depends on many things. What kind of formula? How important is the derivation? Is this a math paper or physics, engineering, economics etc? Pure math or applied math? There really isn’t a single answer that would be universally applicable, you’d better add more details if you want an answer that’s relevant to your particular situation.

Comment: This is what I would do: First write up the derivation of the formula (that way you make sure there are no mistakes). Then, usually I have a better sense whether it fits well or should be added to the appendix. If at the end of the day I choose to remove it, at least I know that I can add it if, say, a referee requests it. I know it is often tempting not to write the computation out of laziness, but I believe it is a bad practice.